# Google Calendar API "change this and all following events"

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, icalendar

When I perform the action on Google Calendar of editing a single instance on the date of "2015-04-29" and all following instances of a recurring set and then fetch the events since the last sync, I get the following commands:

1. Delete the existing recurring set
2. Create a new recurring set: RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;UNTIL=20150429T065959Z; (start_date=2015-04-23)
3. Create a new recurring set: RRULE:FREQ=DAILY; (start_date=2015-04-29)

As you can see, the first recurring set that Google has created says it goes until 2015-04-29, yet at the same time, the start_date of the second recurring set is also 2015-04-29. This is causing an overlap/duplicate event on 2015-04-29. I believe the first recurring set should actually go until 2015-04-28. Is this a bug in the Google Calendar API, or am I understanding the commands wrong?

Comment: Are these all-day or timed events? If all-day then the until sounds wrong. Have you done this all-following change in the Calendar Web UI or in some other app?

Comment: These are timed events. I made the all-following change on the Google Calendar Web UI at calendar.google.com. Even with a timed event, why would the until be on the same day as the start of the second recurrence? I would understand if there was also a single-instance override on that day for the first recurrence, but I'm only getting those 3 commands I listed in the question.

Comment: The until ends one second before the next instance so there should be no overlap and no duplicates.

Comment: That was the answer. Thanks.